# XPath - Scalar has more than one row in the output

Tags: hadoop, xpath, apache-pig

I'm trying to create an alias with information from an XML. My code has this structure.

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A = LOAD 'foo.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('Document') as (x:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'Document/foo/bar/tag') as myTag:chararray;

C = LOAD 'foo.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('someOtherTag') as (x:chararray);

D = FOREACH C GENERATE
    B.myTag,
    XPath(x, 'someOtherTag/taggy') as FOO:chararray;

dump D;
```

When I try to show D or store it I always get an **ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" )**

The error is not very meaningful. How can this be resolved?

## EDIT

Ok, I found out that B has more than one row. It was hard because **illustrate** and **dump** were only showing 1 row, but then I used

```
B_GROUP = GROUP B BY myTag;
B_COUNT = FOREACH B1_GROUP GENERATE COUNT(B);
illustrate B_COUNT
```

It shows now 2 rows for B. How can I remove the additional one?

Comment: you can try grouping, and then selecting the MAX.

    B_GROUP = FOREACH (group all B) generate MAX(B.myTag) as myTag

and then use B_GROUP.myTag

Comment: I have used B = DISTINCT B; and the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use B.mytag in the GENERATE part of a foreach (assuming the FOREACH is not on B), you must first ensure that B only has one row. Otherwise it is unclear which B.mytag you are trying to reference.

Comment: When I dump B I always get only one value in the form of (*value*).